# How to programmatically add members to Exchange Distribution List?

Tags: outlook, exchange-server, distribution-list, gal

I am looking for some sort of code to add members to a Distribution List in GAL. We are moving to a new DL naming convention in the new system and I need to add hundreds of users to new distribution lists without fail. Manually doing this will take ages and I am looking for achieving this programmatic-ally.. I was searching for the past 4hrs with no luck. I don't even know where to start. Any help is appreciated...

Comment: Looking for the same answer as well...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb645998.aspx

Comment: Damn it.. I have spent hours searching MSDN.. :(
How did you find that!