# Outlook VBA Modify Members of Distribution List in GAL

Tags: vba, outlook, exchange-server, distribution-list, gal

I have a distribution list the Global Address List that I am the owner of. I would like to programmatically add/remove members from the list in VBA, instead of via the properties in Outlook.

I can reference the distribution list as an AddressEntry or an ExchangeDistributionList, and access member information like .Alias or .Type, but I cannot perform any add/remove functions. The entry in Microsoft .DistListItem has an AddMembers method but only describes adding members to a new distribution list. I cannot find any code for adding to existing distribution list.

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284249/how-to-programmatically-add-members-to-exchange-distribution-list) asks my question, but the linked answer only shows how to display the members. It does not explain how to add/remove.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that `DistListItem` represents an `IPM.DistList` item in one of your contacts folders in the mailbox. It does not represent a GAL object, which is represented by the `AddressEntry` and `ExchangeDistributionList` objects.

To add a member to a DL, you can use `AddressEntry.Members.Add`